# Large Image Centering

Tags: windows-phone-7

I get from the server image 800X800 in jpg format and i need to display it in center of the WP7 screen. I need to display like example in this url
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/152/examplea.jpg/
I prefer to do this without cropping of image if it possible, because i get new image always in start of application. I tried with stretch, rectangle geometry.
I write this without code example, because this is only insert a image.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what have you tried? how do you show the image now? have you looked on the Image.Stretch Property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: See @ie. comment. Lazy question, lazy answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in Xaml

```
Image name="Image" width = 800 height = 1000 stretch = fill Margin="-215,-120,-255,-184"
```

Then set the source